# Mapreduce wordcount in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, mapreduce, word-count

Well I am new to mapreducer programs. So when i search a example of mapreducer programs all I get is word count program. All the programs related to word count use the text to file as the input. I tried using a csv file as a input and the reducer is not working as it works for text file. 
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/
This is the current example i am looking at. Would someone explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class:

```
from collections import Counter

with open(filename) as handler:
    counter = Counter(handler.read().split())

print(counter.most_common(10))
```

On the documentation you will find a lot of more useful informations.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But my doubt is a different one. I am trying to work on mapreduce programs.

Answer (score -1):

Distinguish between

- [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce): a programming model for parallel execution
- Python: a programming language
- Hadoop: a cluster platform Python can run on

Do you really need the MapReduce for Hadoop or just a pure Python example? If the latter one, it can be much easier than your link:

```
import multiprocessing
def word_count(line, delimiter=","):
    """Worker"""
    summary = {}
    for word in line.strip().split(delimiter):
        if word in summary:
            summary[word] += 1
        else:
            summary[word] = 1
    return summary
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
result = {}
# Map: each line to a separate worker
for summary in pool.imap_unordered(word_count, open("/path/to/file.csv")):
    # Reduce: aggregate the result of each line into one result
    for (word, count) in summary.items():
        result[word] = result[word]+count if word in result else count
print(result)
```

Comment: Since I am currently working on Hadoop platform i would like to know more about Map Reduce programs. Hence I would like to know the answer in that paradigm. Thanks for the help though :)